# Best OR/M for use with Interfaces

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nhibernate, orm, llblgenpro

In our next project we have a need for using interfaces like this (Example code)

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Name {get; set;}
    IList<IBar> Bars {get; set;}
}

public interface IBar
{
    string Name {get;set;}
    IList<IFoo> Foos {get;set;
}


public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public IList<IBar> Bars {get; set;}
}

public class Bar : IBar
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public IList<IFoo> Foos {get;set;}
}
```

Obviously, in the application layer, we wish to be using the interfaces, and have no knowlegde what so ever about the implementing class.

I've been looking at a few OR/M's - We currently own LLBLGen, I have tried EntityFramework and it was a nightmare, didn't get it to work either, looked into NHibernate but the fact that the getting-started procedure is so complicated relative to LLBLGen scared me away (but I am still open for NHibernate if it supports my needs).

So, what I am looking for: A simple OR/M that I can use with minimal setup requirements (LLBLGen you just use their tool to reverse engineer your DB, and generate source code, and you can begin coding), which supports the structure above.

On a side note: Could anyone tell me what the pattern I am looking for is called? (other than ultra-slothfull ;) )

Comment: Entity Framework is far from being a nightmare. I don't know what approach you tried, however, as there are basically 2: Code First and Model First. If you go model-first, you can customize the T4 Template used to generate the entities to generate whatever code (in your case, these interfaces as well)

Comment: @HighCore Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631309/updating-many-to-many-navigation-property-in-entity-framework-6-changes-not-bei - It took me 4 days to get it to work. With LLBLGen, I could call adapter.Save(myEntity); and everything would have worked out of the box. I use DB first with EF.

Comment: yet again, I don't know what you're using. we use the Entity Framework 4.0 with the STE template for a Client/Server application. It works great and doesn't have the problems you're describing there.

Comment: `context.ApplyChanges()` and `context.SaveChanges()` is all that is needed to save the whole object graph to the DB in Entity Framework. I have no idea what is all that stuff of attach and all that. if you `db.ApplyChanges(account)`, then `SaveChanges()` it saves, for example, the account with all its addresses, phones and any related entities.

Comment: @HighCore If it works why did they remove STE's? I used EF 5 or 6 I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// mappings
public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        Map(f => f.Name);
        HasMany(f => f.Bars).KeyColumn("foo_Id");
    }
}

public class BarMap : ClassMap<Bar>
{
    public BarMap()
    {
        Map(f => f.Name);
    }
}

// query
var john = session.Query<IFoo>()
    .Where(f => f.Name == "John")
    .Fetch(f => f.Bars)
    .Single();

Console.Writeline(john.Bars.Count);
```

Comment: use `HasManyToMany(f => f.Bars).Table("LinkTable").ParentKeyColumn("foo_Id").ChildKeyColumn("bar_id");`

Comment: I got this to work, except that whenever I try it, my DB tables keeps getting dropped and recreated. Obviously this is not because of your code, right?

Comment: nope. is there somewhere `SchemaExport` used or autoddl = true in config?

Comment: Yes, it was the .Create thing in the Helper. This actually works, I am surprised at how simple it is! Am yet to try with Interfaces, give me a few minutes and I will report back.

Comment: I can't do this with Interfaces... :/

Comment: I can't have the implementing class use a IList<Foo> when it's interface says IList<IFoo>, and when I do that, NHibernate thinks I want to use a table called IFoo..

Comment: - ok yes I can, by adding the type param in the HasManyToMany<Foo> :D - I will mark as answer once I have tested this more to make sure it doesen't screw me like Entity Framework did.

Comment: `IList<Foo>` is not convertable into `IList<IFoo>` at all. Think of adding `Foo2 : IFoo` to the second would succeed but throws on the first.

Comment: Is there a designer that can generate these mappings from a DB? Interfaces included?

Comment: there are http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/nhdesigner and http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/nhibernate-designer.html there are certainly more. a simple googling should find them

Comment: Yes, I know that, but do they support **INTERFACES** like I am needing, as per my question?

Answer (score 0):

LLBLGen Pro v3.x can generate the interfaces on the entity classes for you (you can specify the name with a macro, and define it at a project level, so it's no work at all), and with a simple template, you can generate the interfaces as well.

Though, are you re-using the interfaces on multiple entities? In that case, you probably want to query by the interface and get all instances of all types implementing the interface back. Not all ORMs support that (I think NHibernate does, our own runtime and EF don't)