# How can I create a generic update method for One to Many structures in Entity Framework 5?

Tags: entity-framework

I am writing a web application, such that I get different objects back from the web that need to be either updated or added to the database. On top of this, I need to check that the owner is not modified. Since a hacker could potentially get an account and send an update to modify the foreign key to the user model. I don't want to have to manually code all of these methods, instead I want to make a simple generic call.

Maybe something as simple as this

```
ctx.OrderLines.AddOrUpdateSet(order.OrderLines, a => a.Order)
```

Based on old persisted records that have a foreign key to Order, and on the new incoming records.

1. Delete old records that are not on the new records list.
2. Add new records that are not on the old records list.
3. Update new records that exist on both lists.

   ```
   ctx.Entry(orderLine).State=EntityState.Deleted;
              ...
   ctx.Entry(orderLine).State=EntityState.Added;
              ...
   ctx.Entry(orderLine).State=EntityState.Modified;
   ```

This gets a bit complicated when the old record is loaded to verify that ownership did not change. I get an error if I don't do.

```
   oldorder.OrderLines.remove(oldOrderLine); //for deletes
   oldorder.OrderLines.add(oldOrderLine); //for adds
   ctx.Entry(header).CurrentValues.SetValues(header); //for modifications
```

With Entity Framework 5 there is a new extension function called AddOrUpdate. And there was a very interesting (please read) [blog entry](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/05/03/the-key-to-addorupdate/#more-183) on how to create this method before it was added.

I'm not sure if this is too much to ask as a question in StackOverflow, any clues on how to approach the problem may be sufficient. Here are my thoughts so far:

a) leverage AddOrUpdate for some of the functionality.

b) create a secondary context hoping to avoid loading order into the context and avoid extra calls.

c) Set the state of all the saved objects to initially deleted.

Comment: It would be nice if someone implemented such a function like this http://goo.gl/IrzTu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After working on this for a while I found an opensource project called GraphDiff here is it's blog entry '[introducing graphdiff for entity framework code first – allowing automated updates of a graph of detached entities](http://refactorthis.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/introducing-graphdiff-for-entity-framework-code-first-allowing-automated-updates-of-a-graph-of-detached-entities/)'. I only began using it but it looks impressive. And it does solve the problem of issuing update/delete/insert for Many to One relationships. It actually generalizes the problem to graphs and allows arbitrary nesting.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have linked to this question from [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631309/updating-many-to-many-navigation-property-in-entity-framework-6-changes-not-bei/14634260?noredirect=1#comment25623911_14634260), I thought I'd throw in some newly-aquired experience with Entity Framework for me.

To achieve a common save method in my generic repository with Entity Framework, I do this. (Please note that the Context is a member of my repository, as I am implementing the Unit of Work pattern as well)

```
public class EFRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal readonly AwesomeContext Context;
    internal readonly DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

    public EFRepository(AwesomeContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        Context = context;
        DbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    // Rest of implementation removed for brevity 

    public void Save(TEntity entity)
    {
        var entry = Context.Entry(entity);
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
            DbSet.Add(entity);
        else entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

Honestly, I can't tell you **why** this works, because I just kept changing the state conditions - however I do have unit (integration) tests to prove that it works. Hopefully someone more into EF than myself can shed some light on this.

Regarding the "cascading updates", I was curious myself as if it would work using the Unit of Work pattern (my question I linked to was when I did not know it existed, and my repositories would basically create a unit of work whenever I wanted to save/get/delete, which is bad), so I threw in a test case in a simple relational DB. Here is a diagram to give you an idea.

[image: Diagram of model relationships]

**IMPORTANT** In order for test case number 2 to work, you need to make your POCO reference properties virtual, in order for EF to provide lazy loading.

The repository implementation is just derived from the generic `EFRepository<TEntity>` as shown above, so I'll leave out that implementation.

These are my test cases, both pass.

```
public class EFResourceGroupFacts
{
    [Fact]
    public void Saving_new_resource_will_cascade_properly()
    {
        // Recreate a fresh database and add some dummy data.
        SetupTestCase();

        using (var ctx = new LocalizationContext("Localization.CascadeTest"))
        {
            var cultureRepo = new EFCultureRepository(ctx);
            var resourceRepo = new EFResourceRepository(cultureRepo, ctx);

            var existingCulture = cultureRepo.Get(1); // First and only culture.
            var groupToAdd = new ResourceGroup("Added Group");
            var resourceToAdd = new Resource(existingCulture,"New Resource", "Resource to add to existing group.",groupToAdd);

            // Verify we got a single resource group.
            Assert.Equal(1,ctx.ResourceGroups.Count());

            // Saving the resource should also add the group.
            resourceRepo.Save(resourceToAdd);
            ctx.SaveChanges();

            // Verify the group was added without explicitly saving it.
            Assert.Equal(2, ctx.ResourceGroups.Count());
        }

        // try creating a new Unit of Work to really verify it has been persisted..
        using (var ctx = new LocalizationContext("Localization.CascadeTest"))
        {
            Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => ctx.ResourceGroups.First(rg => rg.Name == "Added Group"));
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Changing_existing_resources_group_saves_properly()
    {
        SetupTestCase();

        using (var ctx = new LocalizationContext("Localization.CascadeTest"))
        {
            ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            var cultureRepo = new EFCultureRepository(ctx);
            var resourceRepo = new EFResourceRepository(cultureRepo, ctx);



            // This resource already has a group.
            var existingResource = resourceRepo.Get(2);
            Assert.NotNull(existingResource.ResourceGroup); // IMPORTANT: Property must be virtual!
            // Verify there is only one resource group in the datastore.
            Assert.Equal(1,ctx.ResourceGroups.Count());

            existingResource.ResourceGroup = new ResourceGroup("I am implicitly added to the database. How cool is that?");

            // Make sure there are 2 resources in the datastore before saving.
            Assert.Equal(2, ctx.Resources.Count());

            resourceRepo.Save(existingResource);
            ctx.SaveChanges();

            // Make sure there are STILL only 2 resources in the datastore AFTER saving.
            Assert.Equal(2, ctx.Resources.Count());

            // Make sure the new group was added.
            Assert.Equal(2,ctx.ResourceGroups.Count());

            // Refetch from store, verify relationship.
            existingResource = resourceRepo.Get(2);
            Assert.Equal(2,existingResource.ResourceGroup.Id);

             // let's change the group to an existing group
            existingResource.ResourceGroup = ctx.ResourceGroups.First();
            resourceRepo.Save(existingResource);
            ctx.SaveChanges();

            // Assert no change in groups.
            Assert.Equal(2, ctx.ResourceGroups.Count());

            // Refetch from store, verify relationship.
            existingResource = resourceRepo.Get(2);
            Assert.Equal(1, existingResource.ResourceGroup.Id);
        }
    }

    private void SetupTestCase()
    {
        // Delete everything first. Database.SetInitializer does not work very well for me.
        using (var ctx = new LocalizationContext("Localization.CascadeTest"))
        {
            ctx.Database.Delete();
            ctx.Database.Create();

            var culture = new Culture("en-US", "English");
            var resourceGroup = new ResourceGroup("Existing Group");
            var resource = new Resource(culture, "Existing Resource 1",
                                        "This resource will already exist when starting the test. Initially it has no group.");
            var resourceWithGroup = new Resource(culture, "Exising Resource 2",
                                                 "Same for this resource, except it has a group.",resourceGroup);

            ctx.Cultures.Add(culture);
            ctx.ResourceGroups.Add(resourceGroup);
            ctx.Resources.Add(resource);
            ctx.Resources.Add(resourceWithGroup);

            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

It was interesting to learn this, as I was not sure if it would work.

Comment: There is a problem. Simply put, EF marked your entity as attached when you added it the first time. The last test should be split.

Comment: @ArturoHernandez I'm not sure I understand what you mean - both tests pass, and I already use it in production.

Comment: Ok. Maybe I'm crazy. I'd check entry.State before and after your first save, if I'm right it should be "detached" and then "added".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the generic method I concocted. It does use AddOrUpdate from the System.Data.Entity.Migrations namespace. Which may be reloading records from the db, I'll be checking on that later. The usage is

```
ctx.OrderLines.AddOrUpdateSet(l => l.orderId == neworder.Id, 
    l => l.Id, order.orderLines);
```

Here is the code:

```
public static class UpdateExtensions
{
    public static void AddOrUpdateSet<TEntity>(this IDbSet<TEntity> set, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate,
        Func<TEntity, int> selector, IEnumerable<TEntity> newRecords) where TEntity : class
    {
        List<TEntity> oldRecords = set.Where(predicate).ToList();
        IEnumerable<int> keys = newRecords.Select(selector);

        foreach (TEntity newRec in newRecords) 
            set.AddOrUpdate(newRec);

        oldRecords.FindAll(old => !keys.Contains(selector(old))).ForEach(detail => set.Remove(detail));
    }
}
```